# how to create category with code in wordpress using form

Tags: plugin-development

How can I create parent category or child category using html and assign it to parent category if exists otherwise create new category as parent and assign it to my custom post type.

http://prntscr.com/gnwnic
http://prntscr.com/gnwoc7

```
wp_create_category( $cat_name, $parent );
```

using function above getting fetal error

```
function create_cat_form_submit(){

$cat_name = $_POST['cat_name'];

if(!empty($cat_name) || $cat_name !== ''){

    wp_create_category( $cat_name, '' );

   }    
}

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in E:\xampp\htdocs\post_view_counter\wp-content\plugins\tasks\tasks.php:146 Stack trace: #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `wp_create_category()` is part of the admin API you can only rely it's defined if `is_admin() === true`. Instead use [wp_insert_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term). Check the examples in the codex.

Comment: thanks Zlatev, lovely answer, if you please provide me  example as per my code situation, that will be great, if there is any hook involve please also mention that thanks